# Improve performance of qs with multiple filters and exclude statements

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I'm writing an app that has "social media capabilities". You can block someone you can wave to someone etc...

I have `get_queryset` for getting all users you didn't see on the app or blocked them with multiple exclude and filter statements that look like this.

```py
def get_queryset(self):

    current_id = self.request.user.id
    blocked_users = Blocked.objects.filter(user__id=current_id).values('blocked_user')

    users_taken_action = UserWave.objects.filter(user__id=current_id).values('waved_user')

    users_not_taken_action = Profile.objects.exclude(user__in=users_taken_action) \
            .exclude(user__in=blocked_users).exclude(user__id=current_id)

    return users_not_taken_action
```

I'm new to optimization and when I see this function I get a feeling that this is not too efficient. Im wrong or is there a better way to handle this?

**models**

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserWave(models.Model):

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="current_user")
    waved_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="waved_user")

class Blocked(models.Model):
    
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="user_thats_blocking")
    blocked_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="blocked_user")

class Profile(models.Model):

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
from django.db.models import Q
users_not_taken_action = Profile.objects.filter(Q(user__current_user__isnull=True) & Q(user__blocked_user__isnull=True) & ~Q(user_id=current_id))
```